# Create Voronoi of different sizes based on mean and SD

Tags: r, voronoi-thiessen

I have some large polygons that I want to subdivide into smaller Voronoi polygons.
I am using the very helpful function that someone provided here...
[Dividing Polygon into parts which have equal area using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375345/dividing-polygon-into-parts-which-have-equal-area-using-r)

The Voronoi are all roughly the same size though and I want to make them of various sizes but based around a mean and standard deviation that I can provide and alter.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I'm guessing instead of using kmeans to provide centre points for the Voronoi, use random points
[image]
[image]

Comment: You might be able to use the same technique but creating clusters of a size given by the distribution you are trying to approximate. Tricky though, I'm not sure that's a standard function of clustering algorithms.