# Polygon Divider QGIS Plugin creates less equal parts (polygons) than asked

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, splitting

I've installed QGIS 3.16 for Windows. I digitised a polygon layer (limits of a city) and used the Polygon divider plugin to divide it in 10 equal parts (polygons).

However, as a result, it created only 9 equally divided polygons. (When I tested it, asking for 9 equal parts, it did create 9 polygons. But when I tried for an 8 equal parts division, it again gave 7 polygons).

Could please someone enlighten me?

Comment: Maybe you will find this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/how-to-split-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-in-qgis-3 useful. For your question it would be better to see some graphical support of your problem. Besides when asking about issues of a plugin it is better to report directly to the developer via https://github.com/jonnyhuck/RFCL-PolygonDivider/issues. What if you set up *n+1* parts each time you divide your polygon?

Comment: Thank you so much for your immediate response! Will try out your suggestions :)