# QGIS 3.18 Divide polygon by points

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

I have a polygon-layer with the boundaries of a field and a point-layer with several points inside the polygon.

I want to divide the polygon into as many polygons  as points ( 1 polygon with 3 points -> 3 polygons with almost same size).

And if that works - is it possible to do it with a multi-polygon-layer?

[image: What I have]

[image: What I want]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/how-to-split-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-in-qgis-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Voronoi polygons. I used `Buffer region` of 200 %
2. Intersect your polygons with voronoi output

[image]